# Low color of my scale_fill_gradient() stays white

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very basic question about bar graphs here. I am working on the following bar graph :

```
ggplot(bnc_1994_dataset, aes(x=reorder(DM, -Freq), y=Freq, fill=Freq))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="cadetblue", high="royalblue")+
  labs(title="DM raw frequency bar graph", x="DM combination", y="raw frequency")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70))
```

And I get the following output:

[image]

I can't understand why the low values are not displayed in cadetblue, as specified in the `scale_fill_gradient2()` command.

Best,

Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to your question and to your answer.

`scale_fill_gradient()` takes two arguments: `low` and `high`. `scale_fill_gradient2()` needs a third one: `mid`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the function from scale_fill_gradient2() to scale_fill_gradient() has solved my problem, not sure why!